# Turkish character problem in select query - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, turkish

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[Markup]
  ,[Status] FROM [dbxyz].[dbo].[Block] WHERE Name = 'Hakkımızda'
```

Linq2Sql sends this query to SQL Server 2005 but because of the character problem (ı) it does not get the right dataset as a response. No rows returns.

I can not change the collation of database because it is a hosted service and I have no right to do so. I tried to change collation in column level but it did not work.
What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type for the `name` column?  Hopefully something that starts with "n", like NCHAR, NVARCHAR, etc?

Comment: I dunno LINQ, but `WHERE Name = N'Hakkımızda'` should work

Comment: Yes, it works fine with N. But I don't know how to implement it with Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the column `Block` in the database declared with the proper collation? [Introduce the Turkish I issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/qingsongyao/archive/2009/02/13/introduce-the-turkish-i-issue.aspx). Note that the collation must be declared *even for Unicode Nchars*.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm gonna use ExecuteQuery. ( Bad job! :( )

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx